# Metrics or evaluation about machine learning translation

Tags: machine-learning, translation

Could you guys recommend some evaluation or metrics about machine learning for translation: for example Japanese to English et al. If possible, could you tell me some papers about metrics. I am a new one to translation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite continuous critics and debates starting with [this 2006 article](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/miles/papers/eacl06.pdf), **BLEU** (***B***i**L**ingual **E**valuation **U**nderstudy) score is still the most commonly used metric for machine translation. According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU),

> BLEU is an algorithm for evaluating the quality of text which has been machine-translated from one natural language to another. Quality is considered to be the correspondence between a machine's output and that of a human: "the closer a machine translation is to a professional human translation, the better it is" – this is the central idea behind BLEU. BLEU was one of the first metrics to achieve a high correlation with human judgements of quality, and remains one of the most popular automated and inexpensive metrics.

More specifically, if you want to look at Japanese-English translation, there was a [class project from Stanford CS 224d](https://cs224d.stanford.edu/reports/GreensteinEric.pdf) that translates simple Japanese sentences like 「彼女は敵だった」 into English with neural network techniques, and uses BLEU as the evaluation metric.

If you want more readings on machine translation, I suggest a good start with one of the most influential one recently, namely [Neural machine translation by jointly learning to align and translate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473) by Yoshua Bengio et al. You can also look at the [top papers that cited the BLEU critics](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8900239586727494087) to get a sense of other commonly used metrics.

Comment: Hi @Jiāgěng, thanks for your kind answer, it is helpful to me. How about other metrics for machine translation.

Comment: As I mentioned, You can also look at the top papers that cited the BLEU critics to get a sense of other commonly used metrics, for example, the Amazon Mechanical Turk one that comes up on the top. See https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8900239586727494087